# Python Pandas - adding column names using For statement

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to import [Semeion Handwritten Digit Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/semeion/semeion.data) as a pandas DataFrame, but the first row is being taken as column names.

```
df.head()
   0.0000  0.0000.1  0.0000.2  0.0000.3  0.0000.4  0.0000.5  1.0000  1.0000.1  \
0     0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       1.0     1.0       1.0   
1     0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0       0.0   
2     0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     1.0       1.0   
3     0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0     0.0       0.0   
4     0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       1.0       1.0     1.0       1.0   

   1.0000.2  1.0000.3 ...   1  0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  
0       1.0       1.0 ...   1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  
1       0.0       1.0 ...   1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  
2       1.0       1.0 ...   1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  
3       0.0       1.0 ...   1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  
4       1.0       1.0 ...   1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  

[5 rows x 266 columns]
```

Since the DataFrame has 266 columns, I am trying to assign numbers as column names, using lambda and a for loop.... using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/semeion/semeion.data", delimiter = r"\s+",
                names = (lambda x: x for x in range(0,266)) )
```

But am getting weird column names, like:

```
>>> df.head(2)
   <function <genexpr>.<lambda> at 0x04F4E588>  \
0                                          0.0   
1                                          0.0   

   <function <genexpr>.<lambda> at 0x04F4E618>  \
0                                          0.0   
1                                          0.0   

   <function <genexpr>.<lambda> at 0x04F4E660>  \
0                                          0.0   
1                                          0.0
```

If I remove the parenthesis, then the code throws a syntax error:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/semeion/semeion.data", delimiter = r"\s+",
                names = lambda x: x for x in range(0,266) )
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone tell me:

1) How to get column names as numbers... from 0 to 266

2) If in case I get a DataFrame with first row as column names, how do I push it down and add new column names, without losing the first row?

TIA

Comment: Thanks... It worked! But, what is wrong in my lambda code?

Comment: I think problem is it need list of columns names, so `range` is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need parameter `header=None` or `names=range(266)` for set default names of columns in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/semeion/semeion.data"
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep = r"\s+", header=None)
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep = r"\s+", names=range(266))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try something like:

```
my_columns = [range(266)]
```

Comment: oh sorry, I will just keep the second part then